# Twitter API location of tweets

Tags: twitter

I'm thinking up a new website idea which would allow a visitor to view on a map where certain things have happened. I want to use Twitter, with the idea that someone tweets using a specific hashtag. I want to capture that tweet using the API and find the location of where the tweet came from. Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do something like Foursquare?

Comment: Similar, but not quite as complicated. It would rely on the location of people who are making the tweets to the specific hashtag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. However there are lots of tweets (a majority in reality) which do not get any location and it is impossible to get it for these ones. To be located, a user must enable location in its account parameters and give its location with the tweet while posting it but a majority of tweeps do not do that.

For retrieving tweets location, you just have to download the tweet with [the corresponding Twitter API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) (`GET statuses/show/:id`). Once you get the tweet, search its `"coordinates"` field. This field has got a subfield also called `"coordinates"`. This subfield is a list with two numbers : `[longitude, latitude]`. For further information, refer to the Twitter Developers documentation about [tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) and [coordinates](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets#obj-coordinates).