# Find twitter users based on their location

Tags: python, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to find twitter users based on their location. Ideally it should be  their **current location**, but if it's just their original location, that might do as well. For example, if a person is from Brazil, but today they're in Germany, I'd like to be able to find them as "in Germany" twitter user.

Also, I'd like to be able to know their current city, not just country, if possible.

Can I do that via the **Twitter API**? How?

I don't want to use any 3rd-party services which offer this directly as service, however, using 3rd-party services from which I can myself find out their current location indirectly is OK. For example, if in Facebook they recently have posted a photo "I'm already in Germany, yeaahhhh" -- that sort of things. Of course, I prefer the Twitter API.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812579/twitter-api-location-of-tweets

Comment: @Adib, no, that's different and outdated.

Comment: Have you looked through this? https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries Also, have you looked at this? https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid The documentation makes it easy and straightforward in regards to what you want: `==About Geo==

If there is no geotag for a status, then there will be an empty <geo/> or "geo" : {}. This can only be populated if the user has used the Geotagging API to send a statuses/update.`

Comment: @Adib, you don't understand? I want to find users by location! Not find the location of a given user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're basically looking for is geo-tagged information. But, you want to find users based on their location. The answer you'll get isn't an easy "Yes" or "No", it's literally based on what you're trying to accomplish. However, since you're asking about Twitter API, the Twitter API **cannot** do what you want, but there are ways around it.

Your question focuses primarily on how you can find users in a given location. For the example below, let's say the location is "Berlin, DE"

At present, for what you're asking, Twitter API has two methods for you to capture location based information.

**[User Search Method (`users/search`):](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search)**

According to Twitter's documentation, it states that this function will return you users based on whatever query you provide. To quote:

> [*users/search*] Provides a simple, relevance-based search interface to public user
> accounts on Twitter. Try querying by topical interest, full name,
> company name, **location**, or other criteria. Exact match searches are
> not supported.

The location information, however, is **not** based on their tweets. Rather, it's based on their profile location information (the information the user types in when they first create their Twitter profile).

Therefore, using the *Berlin, DE* example: Jason lives in California, USA (and his profile reflects the fact that he is from San Jose, California), but he is recently visiting Berlin and is actively tweeting there. Including tagging his tweets with his location and all. Now if you do a users/search with the query *Berlin, DE*, you'll not find Jason in the results because his profile's location is set to San Jose, California.

**[Tweets Search Method (`search/tweets`):](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets)**

According to Twitter's documentation, this method will return you the tweets (up to 450 tweets with APP authorization) based on whatever query you provide, including location. Using the `geocode` query, you can find the information you need in a given location. To quote:

> Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given
> latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the
> Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The
> parameter value is specified by “latitude,longitude,radius”, where
> radius units must be specified as either “mi” (miles) or “km”
> (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API
> to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode
> parameter to search near geocodes directly. A maximum of 1,000
> distinct “sub-regions” will be considered when using the radius
> modifier.

Given the *Berlin, DE* example, if you use this method, you'll actually find Jason's tweets because they're tagged to Berlin. This method **does not** return the profile/user information that you want. But, you can leverage this method to get the user information.

In essence, you can parse through all the tweets and collect the user ids, which is exactly what you want. This is the best solution present that is visible and accessible via the API.

Comment: so, in general, it's possible, but not accurate, correct?

Comment: `In essence, you can parse through all the tweets and collect the user ids, which is exactly what you want. This is the best solution present that is visible and accessible via the API.` --> if and only if they contain location-related hash tags, otherwise, there's no way, correct?

Comment: @Ommonnna It can be hashtags `AND` location: you can create a query that can contain both geocode and hashtag queries (this will basically create a subset of tweets that have geo information and hashtag/text). If you wish to find tweets that are not geo-tagged, but may potentially have hashtag to a location, then you run a tweet search without the geocode query. In other words, you run two set of tweets search (one with geo query only and one with hashtag query that contains geo information `e.g. #berlin`)

Comment: I think the URLs are now (1)
 https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search and (2)  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets